# Entity Framework appears to skip mapping a table with a multi-column primary key set through a constraint

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

I've created an ADO.NET model via the database first approach.

One of my tables which is listed when creating the model doesn't actually get added to it.

The table has a multi-column primary key, composed of two foreign keys.

```
CREATE TABLE ForumAccess
(
    UserID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(UserID) NOT NULL,
    ForumID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Forums(ForumID) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ForumAccessID PRIMARY KEY (UserID, ForumID),
);
```

It does show up when I have to select which tables to add, but then it seems to be skipped. No class is generated for it, and it's not shown in the `.edmx` file.

Part of my application depends on the existence of this table. I have another table which has a multi-column primary key, and another DateTime type column. That table does get added.

That table is:

```
CREATE TABLE Moderators
(
    UserID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(UserID) NOT NULL,
    ForumID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Forums(ForumID) NOT NULL,
    TimeOfAddition DateTime NOT NULL, -- When the mod was added as a mod.
    CONSTRAINT ModeratorID PRIMARY KEY (UserID, ForumID),
);
```

Why does the `Moderators` table get added, but the `ForumAccess` table doesn't?

There is no error, or any warning that I can see.

What am I missing?

Comment: I've never done this myself, but are you sure it is not getting added as a navigation property of Users and Forums? If you have a table with just those two IDs and nothing else, that is really all it is.

Comment: It doesn't appear as a navigation property either. I think I'll have to add another column, like "TimeOfAddition", to make it visible.

Comment: Are you sure? I just tested this, and my Forum table has a navigation property "Users" that is a collection of users, my User table has the other end called "Forums", which is a collection of Forums. The ForumAccess Name is in the model browser, but as an association, not an entity. It won't make a separate entity unless it needs to (ie you add another column)

Comment: In the end I added another column to create an entity. Maybe I just didn't understand the navigation properties. But I couldn't see "ForumAccess" anywhere there. Anyway, I've just worked around it by adding another DateTime field to the table.